# excel - find value in column A return prespecified number

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a big list of professions in column A which can be written on several ways. In Column B I want to search the limited professions listed in Column C and if there is a match with one in Column A I want to return the value from column D which is associated with the profession from column C in column B. So for every match with `*teacher*` I want 1165 to show up in column B. For every match with `*driver*`5468. And so on. I tried to do this with Vlookup but it doesn't seem to be able to handle this. I turned to the following:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("teacher";A1));"1165";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("driver";A1));"5468";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("postman";9874));"1";" ")))`

This could do the trick but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way? Instead of putting everything in very long nested if statements...

```
  A              B           C                D
Driver           ?         Teacher            1165
Teacher          ?         Driver             5468
Truckdriver      ?         Postman            9874
Works as teacher ?  
Driver           ?
Postman          ?
Works as postman ?
Teacher          ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do would require lots of nested if statements, if you are trying to do this strictly with formulas and now VBA. And if you set this up differently you could do this with hlookup. Comment and let me know if you want me to show you how to do that.

But, since you used excel-vba as the tag, I believe that you are looking for a vba solution. One way to do that is like this:

```
for each cell in range("D1:D3")
    for each cell2 in range("A1:A8")
      if cell2.value = cell.value then cell2.offset(0,1).value = cell.offset(0,1).value
    next
next
```

Mind you, this would not be everything you would write in the module, but it is a good start. Also, the ranges would need to be changed to suit whatever the range ctually is where your values are kept.

And the offsets are assuming that the data you need is one column to the right (e.g., cell.offset(0,1) would be 1165 for teacher, for example.

Comment: Tnx for the answer. I'll check the vba some more in depth.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the answer if you feel it is sufficient.